# How to make this tailwind code snippet simpler

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I have this piece of code that I am using for my personal portfolio, but its such a pain to update and tbh to look at as well. I was wondering if anyone can simplify this piece of code with keeping the same effects. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<section class="space-y-5 py-10">
      <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold text-center">Timeline</h2>
      <div>
        <div class="flex space-x-2 sm:space-x-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <p>2022</p>
            <div class="border-color h-full w-px border-l border-skin-base">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col space-y-5 pb-5">
            <p>
              Developed full-stack MERN application while a part of{" "}
              <a
                href="https://www.joincolab.io/"
                class="text-skin-accent hover:underline"
              >
                Co.Lab</a
              >
            </p>
            <p>
              Graduated from{" "}
              <a
                class="text-skin-accent hover:underline"
                href="https://www.dominican.edu/"
              >
                Dominican University of California
              </a>{" "}
              with a bachelor&apos;s degree in computer science
            </p>
            <p>
              Started Volunteering with CodeNation to help students learn web
              development
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex space-x-2 sm:space-x-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <p>2020</p>
            <div class="border-color h-full w-px border-l border-skin-base">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col space-y-5 pb-5">
            <p>Graduated from Berkeley High School</p>
            <p>
              Completed{" "}
              <a
                class="text-skin-accent hover:underline"
                href="https://codenation.org/"
              >
                Code Nation
              </a>{" "}
              Pandora program
            </p>
            <p>
              Participant of{" "}
              <a
                class="text-skin-accent hover:underline"
                href="https://buildyourfuture.withgoogle.com/programs/computer-science-summer-institute"
              >
                Google&apos;s Computer Science Summer Institute
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex space-x-2 sm:space-x-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <p>2019</p>
            <div class="border-color h-full w-px border-l border-skin-base">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col space-y-5 pb-5">
            <p>
              Joined my High School&apos;s Robotics Club{" "}
              <a
                class="text-skin-accent hover:underline"
                href="https://team5419.org/"
              >
                Team 5419 Berkelium
              </a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex space-x-2 sm:space-x-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
            <p>2018</p>
            <div class="border-color h-full w-px border-l border-skin-base">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p>Wrote my first line of code</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

As you can see its a huge tree of code thats a lot to work with.

[image: output of the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet as well as a Tailwind Play on how I would structure it. Some of the styling may not be the same but if you end up using this structure I have confidence that you are able to add whatever style you need.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/s1S4P9JxHB

```html
<!-- timeline -->
<section>
  <!-- container -->
  <div>
    <!-- title -->
    <div>
      <h1>Timeline Bruh</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- 2018 -->
    <div class="flex gap-8">
      <div>
        <h1>2018</h1>
        <div class="bg-gray-200 h-20 w-1 rounded-sm mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Worked on cool stuff with friends</p>
        <p>Learned how to do cool stuff</p>
        <p>Drove a car to hawaii</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 2019 -->
    <div class="flex gap-8">
      <div>
        <h1>2019</h1>
        <div class="bg-gray-200 h-20 w-1 rounded-sm mx-auto"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Went to hospital for rabbies</p>
        <p>Joined the Army</p>
        <p>Learned piano</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 2020 -->
    <div class="flex gap-8">
      <div>
        <h1>2020</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Watched Batman the movie</p>
        <p>Ate greek food for the first time</p>
        <p>Learned guitar</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```